# Iterate over column names and separate fields recursively with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to iterate over column names of the data frame, then using **dplyr**, separate fields using a delimiter(->) found among the row fields. This is how the dataset looks like :

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = c("Silva->Mark", "Brandon->Livo", "Mango->Apple"),
               v2 = c("Austin",  "NA ", "Orange"),
               v3 = c("James -> Jacy","NA->Jane", "apple -> Orange")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Now I wrote a code that filters out column names with delimiter(->) on rows which are *column v1* and *column v3*. Here is the code:

```
rows_true <- apply(df,2,function(x) any(sapply(x,function(y)grepl("->",y))))
ss<-df[,rows_true]
```

Then I tried to loop through those column names so that I can separate using the delimiter using this code but it ain't working

```
cols<- names(df)

if (names %in% df){
splitcols <- ss %>%
  tidyr::separate(cols, into = c(paste0(names,+ "old"), "paste0(names,+ "New")"), sep = "->")
}
```

The reason I am using ***paste0*** is because I do want the columns split into two using the delimiter then the newly formed columns should be named using the original name plus suffix ***Old*** for the first one and ***New*** for second split column

End result after looping through column names and recursively separating them should look like this

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1_Old = c("Silva", "Brandon", "Mango"),
               v1_New = c("Mark", "Livo", "Apple"),
               v3_Old = c("James","NA", "apple"),
               v3_New = c("Jacy","Jane", "Orange")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution which uses `data.table()`.

There are some differences to the other answers posted so far:

- It is not required to identify the columns to be split beforehand. Instead, columns without `"->"` are dropped from the result  *on the fly*.
- The regular expression which is used for splitting includes surrounding white space (if any)
  `" *-> *"`. This avoids to call `trimws()` on the resulting pieces afterwards or to remove white space beforehand.

.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)   # piping used to improve readability
setDT(df)
lapply(names(df), function(x) {
  mDT <- df[, tstrsplit(get(x), " *-> *")]
  if (ncol(mDT) == 2L) setnames(mDT, paste0(x, c("_Old", "_New")))
}) %>% as.data.table()
```

> ```
>     v1_Old v1_New v3_Old v3_New
> 1:   Silva   Mark  James   Jacy
> 2: Brandon   Livo     NA   Jane
> 3:   Mango  Apple  apple Orange
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility involving `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 select(v1, v3) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 separate_rows(val, sep = "->", convert = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 mutate(val = trimws(val),
        var = make.unique(var)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  v1      v1.1  v3    v3.1  
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 Silva   Mark  James Jacy  
2 Brandon Livo  <NA>  Jane  
3 Mango   Apple apple Orange
```

Or to further match the expected output:

```
df %>%
 select(v1, v3) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 separate_rows(val, sep = "->", convert = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(rowid, var) %>%
 mutate(val = trimws(val),
        var2 = if_else(row_number() == 2, paste0(var, "_old"), paste0(var, "_new"))) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-var) %>%
 spread(var2, val) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  v1_new  v1_old v3_new v3_old
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Silva   Mark   James  Jacy  
2 Brandon Livo   <NA>   Jane  
3 Mango   Apple  apple  Orange
```

Comment: Can you edit it so that I only get columns split, like I don't want to have V2  in the result since I have multiple columns and it will be hard to analyze  having those not split in the last result

Answer (score 1):

A different approach with `dplyr`, `purr`, and `stringr` is the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# Detect the columns with at least on "->"
my_df_cols <- map_lgl(my_df, ~ any(str_detect(., "->")))

my_df %>% 
  # Select only the columns with at least "->"
  select(which(my_df_cols)) %>% 
  # Mutate these columns and only keep the mutated columns with new names
  transmute_all(list(old = ~ str_split(., "->", simplify = TRUE)[, 1], 
                     new = ~ str_split(., "->", simplify = TRUE)[, 2]))

#    v1_old v3_old v1_new  v3_new
# 1   Silva James    Mark    Jacy
# 2 Brandon     NA   Livo    Jane
# 3   Mango apple   Apple  Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
#Detect columns with "->"
cols <- names(df)[colSums(sapply(df, grepl,  pattern = "->")) > 1]
#Remove unwanted whitespaces before and after "->"
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols],  function(x) gsub("\\s+", "", x))

#Split into new columns specifying sep as "->"
splitstackshape::cSplit(df[cols], cols, sep = "->")

#      v1_1  v1_2  v3_1   v3_2
#1:   Silva  Mark James   Jacy
#2: Brandon  Livo  <NA>   Jane
#3:   Mango Apple apple Orange
```